# Воспроизведение звука, запакованного в .qrc

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyglet

Нужен звук на нажатие клавиш, из опробованных библиотек остановился на `pyglet`, шустрая и отлично работает с одновременным воспроизведением. Однако после запаковки ресурсов в `.qrc` файл, оказалось что она, по всей видимости, не умеет работать в таком формате и выдаёт ошибку `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: ':sound/type.wav'`.
С подключением и файлами ресурсов всё в порядке, изображения и гифки работают нормально.
Какие есть варианты решения этой проблемы? Не хотелось бы иметь дополнительные файлы с дистрибутивом, поэтому хочу запаковать.

Насколько я понял, `.qrc` переводит файлы в двоичный код, однако во всей информации, что я нарыл об этой системе, она использовалась исключительно для изображений.

```
import pyglet
import qrc_resources

sound = ':sound/type.mp3'
song = pyglet.media.load(sound, streaming=False)
song.play()
```

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="sound">
    <file>type.mp3</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: приведите код. по кофейной гуще никто гадать не будет

Comment: @Sergey Tatarincev дык вопрос скорее теоретического характера, кода там на две строчки с документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось, `pyglet` действительно не может работать с запакованными в `rcc` данными. Выход из этой ситуации - распаковывать содержимое во временную папку перед использованием.

```
temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    sound_data = QtCore.QResource(sound).data()
    sound_name = sound.split("/")[-1]
    sound_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, sound_name)

    with open(sound_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(sound_data)
```

Теперь можно подключать в `pyglet` переменную `sound_path`.